# How to copy keyframes in the timeline from start to end without copy pasting

Tags: animation, timeline

I have an object which animates up and down, from frame 0 to 20. In order to replicate this motion, until frame 250, I select the first 2 frames copy, then move the scroll bar, to the next frames then past, and I repeat this process. Is there a shortcut how to copy paste more swiftly?

[image]

Comment: Using a _Cycles_ modifier like @Chris shows in his answer is the better, more elegant solution. If you want to do it manually, select the keyframes you want to repeat and do not copy them, but duplicate them with `Shift`+`D` and move them to the frame where you want them. This way duplicating and moving is a single action and you can repeat it afterwards by pressing `Shift`+`R` as many times as you want to duplicate the keyframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy your keyframe one more time to 40, then use the cycles modifier:

[image]

[image]

[image]